# Python tornado Too many open files Ssl

Tags: python, django, ssl, tornado

If i have many connection on my tornado server, i se error on log

```
Exception in callback (<socket._socketobject object at 0x7f0b9053e3d0>, <function null_wrapper at 0x7f0b9054c140>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 276, in accept_handler
    callback(connection, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 264, in _handle_connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 517, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context = ssl_options_to_context(ssl_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 494, in ssl_options_to_context
    context.load_cert_chain(ssl_options['certfile'], ssl_options.get('keyfile', None))
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

and disconnect my client. Tornado open ssl certificate file on ewery connect?

Tornado app

```
class VastWebSocket(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
connections = set()
current_connect = 0
current_user = 0
status_play_vast = False

def open(self):
    c = Connection()
    c.connection = self

VastWebSocket.connections.add(c)
self.current_connect = c

def on_message(self, msg):

data = json.loads(msg)

app_log.info("on message = " + msg)

if not 'status' in data:
  return

if data["status"] == "start_vast":
  VastWebSocket.status_play_vast = True

if data["status"] == "end_vast":
  VastWebSocket.status_play_vast = False

app_log.info("status_play_vast = " + str(VastWebSocket.status_play_vast))

if data["status"] == "get_status_vast":
  self.current_connect.connection.write_message({"status": VastWebSocket.status_play_vast})
  return

for conn in self.connections:
        conn.connection.write_message(msg)


def on_close(self):
if self.current_connect <> 0:
  VastWebSocket.connections.remove(self.current_connect)


def check_origin(self, origin):
return True
```

Start tornado server from django command

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Starts the Tornado application for message handling.'

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('port_number', nargs='+', type=int)

def sig_handler(self, sig, frame):
    """Catch signal and init callback"""
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback(self.shutdown)

def shutdown(self):
    """Stop server and add callback to stop i/o loop"""
    self.http_server.stop()

    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    io_loop.add_timeout(time.time() + 2, io_loop.stop)

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if "port_number" in options:
        try:
            port = int(options["port_number"][0])
        except ValueError:
            raise CommandError('Invalid port number specified')
    else:
        port = 8030

    ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain(os.path.join("/www/cert/", "rumma.crt"),
            os.path.join("/www/cert/", "rumma.key"))

    self.http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options = ssl_ctx)


    self.http_server.bind(port, address="0.0.0.0")
    self.http_server.start(1)
    # Init signals handler
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.sig_handler)

    # This will also catch KeyboardInterrupt exception
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.sig_handler)

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Why his open many file, in my mind need open ssl in start server and all.
Stackoverflow asks more info, but in top, all info all need.

Comment: The call to `load_cert_chain` in the stack trace is only supposed to be used when `ssl_options` is a dict. But it's an `ssl.SSLContext` in this example, so you're doing the right thing and it shouldn't have to load the certificate again. Are you sure that this setup code matches this stack trace? Do you have anywhere else where you pass `ssl_options` as a dict?

Comment: My bad, trace for this code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/netutil.py", line 264, in accept_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 206, in accept
error: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Comment: OK, in that case you're not reopening the certificate every time, you're just running out of file descriptors (and lee-pai-long's answer below should help)

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to run multiple process or thread that all accessing to the ssl keyfile directly. Linux default `ulimit` is quick low and this error then occurs.

You can check the current setting with:

```
$ ulimit -a
```

The quick and dirty solution is to increase this value:

```
$ ulimit -n <new_value>
```

Even `unlimited` is accepted with the `-n` option.

*Note: You can permanently set the value the app user `.bashrc` file.*

In both case you'll need to log out then log in for the change to take effect.

But modifying this value is a bit dirty because it's a global value for a given user environment.

The harder but cleaner solution is to find a way to load the content of the file in memory when your app load and make the loaded value/variable accessible for all processes.

Comment: my ulimit -n
200000
im change /etc/security/limits.conf to

root            soft    nproc            200000
root            hard    nproc            1000000
root            soft    nofile            200000
root            hard    nofile           1000000

Im see this error, after 1024 count connect.

Comment: Are you sure this is the setting for the user that start tornado ? If so you'll have to find a way to load the file only once. I'm not super familiar with tornado, does it spawn a different process/thread for each request ?

Comment: In my mind limit ulimit load from  /etc/security/limits.conf with start system

Comment: I, add ulimit -n 200000 in /root/.bashrc
But i have same problem, host have one user, just root.

Comment: I think you need to log out in log for the  value to take effect.